# Providing custom validation message

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

We have a form with fields loaded from a model. For a currency field, the client wants a specific error message for values less than the minimum value or greater than the maximum value.

It is easy to set the minimum and maximum values using `setMinValue` and `setMaxValue`, say in `onAfterRender`, but there doesn't appear to be a way to set the error message.

There is a `setActiveError` call, but I'm not sure how to hook it in. Is it possible to provide a custom form validation?

We have access to the data model definition, so we could add a `validator`, but a complication is that it isn't always the case that this validation is required.

We also have access to `initComponent` for the form, but note the form is loaded from a model, so no `config`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are configurable using a template, see minText & maxText here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Number-cfg-minText

Something like:

```
initComponent: function() {
    this.minText = 'Not enough! More than ${0} ok?';
    this.maxText = 'Too much! Less than ${0}';
    this.callParent();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it even works in `afterrender`. Sometimes it's the simplest things that trip you up...